# Adding ClassLoader to the Tomcat

Tags: tomcat6, classloader

I have a JAR file with most of the business logic. My web application, developed in Spring MVC, uses that JAR file. To secure the JAR file, I used JarCryp. JarCryp has created a .sjar file from the JAR file. Now, to load the JAR file from Tomcat, I have aded  to the Tomcat context.i.e.Added following line to context.xml

```
 <Loader className="ComponioSampleClassLoader" ></Loader>
```

Where ***ComponioSampleClassLoader*** class has extended ***org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader***.

Now, when I start the tomcat, I get following error

```
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Mar 1, 2013 11:50:41 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
SEVERE: End event threw exception

    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:928)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:193)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:229)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1138)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:793)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:732)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:1018)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4448)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
    Mar 1, 2013 11:50:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processContextConfig
    SEVERE: Parse error in context.xml for /host-manager
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2806)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2832)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:793)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:732)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:1018)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4448)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:928)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:193)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:229)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1138)
        ... 40 more
```

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Just struggled with the same problem for a couple of HOURS...

You need to extend from WebappLoader (org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader) not WebappClassLoader.

You'll notice the constructors for both are the same, so your constructors would most likely not need to change when making this change.

```
package tomcat7;

import org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader;

public class Tomcat7CustomWebappLoader extends WebappLoader {

    public Tomcat7CustomWebappLoader() {
        super();
    }

    public Tomcat7CustomWebappLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }
}
```

The extension from WebappLoader is also evident when looking at the "VirtualWebappLoader" (org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader) Loader implementation packaged with Tomcat.

No experience with your specific use case unfortunately, but a Loader needs to extend WebappLoader.

A more advanced implementation near the bottom of the page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444245/deployment-issues-with-spring-app-in-tomcat-6-0)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, even in the link you mentioned, the accepted answer is extending WebappClassLoader. Has it solved your problem? I will try it now and get back with the results.

Comment: Okay, that link seems to be wrong then - except if that is the naming convention in Tomcat6. In Tomcat7 I needed to extend WebappLoader for my Loader implementation. Inside the WebappLoader there is a field referencing WebappClassLoader (which for your implementation you might need to subclass as well - not sure)

Comment: Just picked up something else that will be useful. You can specify both the Loader and Classloader subclass in the <Loader /> tag. For the Classloader subclass you will need to use the "loaderClass" attribute NOT "className" as in your question (the latter is for the Loader subclass). Search for the attribute names in the documentation [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/loader.html)

Comment: :- I tried loaderClass attribute as well, but no luck. I also tried with WebappLoader, but it has not worked as well.

Comment: Then I've got no idea - sorry.  I got the "argument type mismatch" error and when I inherited from the correct superclass my problem was resolved.